# Spring Security intercept URL not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-security

It works fine when I enter url "app_name/dashboard" and it takes me to login page. When I enter "app_name/dashboard/morestuff" it takes me directly to this url but I'm expecting it to take me to the login page again.

**Spring security configuration is as follow**

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/comment" access="ROLE_USER" /> -->
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>

</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServiceImpl" >  
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: You haven't secured `/dashboard/morestuff`... So yes it will take you to that url. `/dashbord*` doesn't include `/dashboard/morestuff` add `/dashboard/**` as well.

Comment: ohhh yeah i was just thinking about it as well.. let me add it and test it!!!

Comment: @Deinum it worked for me ... thank you so much !!!